# 404 and 405 response when sending AJAX post request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to collect information from a form without having to reload the page but every time I get a response back with 404 or 405. I've tried to use different routes like '/', '/index.html', and 'index.html' but it just keeps loading until it times out or gives me an error. The information goes through because I get an email from nodemailer but on the client side the browser just keeps loading. I am thinking the route is wrong but I am new to AJAX, so can anyone help me with this? Also, I'm using just Vanilla Javascript.

Here's my code:

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');

http.onload = () => {
    submit.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        const alertMessage = document.querySelector('.alert');
        const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
        const name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
        if (name === '' || email === '') {
                    alertMessage.innerHTML = 'Name And Email Required';
                    console.log(name)
                } else {
                    alertMessage.innerHTML = 'Success! Someone will be in touch with you soon!'
                    // email.value = '';
                    // form.reset();
                }
    });
}

http.open('POST', '/index.html', true);
http.send();
```

FORM

```
 <div class="contactform">
                <div class="alert"></div>
                <form action="/index.html" method="POST" class="form">
                    <input type="text" name='name' id='name' placeholder="Name">
                    <input type="email" name='email' id='email' placeholder="Email">
                    <textarea class="messages" name="messages" placeholder="Message...."></textarea>
                    <button class="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
</div>
```

Express Code

```
// Index Route
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){

});

app.post("/index.html", (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email; 
    const messages = req.body.messages;
    console.log(messages, email, name);
    console.log(req.body);
    var userData = new Form(req.body);
    userData.save()
      .then(item =>{
        async function main() {
            // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
            // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
            let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

            // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
              host: "smtp.gmail.com",
              port: 587,
              secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
              auth: {
                user: 'jalissaw32', 
                pass: 'Winchester32@' 
              },
              tls: {
                  rejectUnauthorized: false
              }
            });

            // send mail with defined transport object
            let info = await transporter.sendMail({
              from: email, // sender addresss
              cc: email, 
              to: "<jalissa_williams@yahoo.com>",
              subject: name, 
              text: messages, 
              html: messages, 
            });

            console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

            console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
          }

          main().catch(console.error);

      })
      .catch(err =>{
        res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
      });
});
```

Comment: 404 means "not found" (your URL is not correct) and 405 means "Method not allowed" (you're trying an HTTP method for a URL that is not supported). https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Also, you're probably not calling `preventDefault` on the submit event, so that means your code will be doing both a form post and an XHR request.

Comment: You need to add a success response

Answer (score -1):

Your express server needs to send a response like:

```js
res.sendStatus(200);
```

https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.sendStatus

The client should be changed to:

```js
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
submit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const alertMessage = document.querySelector('.alert');
        const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
        const name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
        if (name === '' || email === '') {
                    alertMessage.innerHTML = 'Name And Email Required';
                    console.log(name)
        } else {
                    alertMessage.innerHTML = 'Success! Someone will be in touch with you soon!'
                    // email.value = '';
                    // form.reset();
        }

        const http = new XMLHttpRequest();

        http.onload = () => {
          console.log("email sent!");
        };

        http.open('POST', '/index.html', true);
        http.send();
});
```

Comment: Hi, i thought if you are collecting information, you go with a POST method?

Comment: Collecting information should be done via a GET method.

Comment: So I would also change the action on the form to a GET request?

Comment: yes, change to a get request and also respond via res.send() on the express server

Comment: Also maybe consider to change the server route name, as it is an api request.
To something like: "/send-mail" instead of "/index.html"

Comment: How do I change the route name and by changing it to get method, it worked but it refreshes the page and my success message doesn't appear. I thought an Ajax request wasn't suppose to refresh the page.

Comment: I updated my answer with the website code. You need to send the request when submited the form and then prevent the form submit with e.preventDefault();